# The remote server returned an error (406) campaign monitor

Tags: c#, request-headers, http-status-code-406, campaign-monitor

I am using create-sent.net version 2.2 for CampaignMonitor. But recently I get this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.
>
> at createsend_dotnet.HttpHelper.MakeRequest[T,U,EX](String method, CreateSendCredentials authCredentials, String path, NameValueCollection queryArguments, T payload)

from the service. Would there be any problem in HTTP header `content-type`?

Answer (score 4):

Figured out the problem. The API was moved to **HTTPS** only. but inside our Http Request, we used **HTTP** URL. due to that reason the API returns (406) Not Acceptable code.

Answer (score 1):

Your service is saying that the response type returned is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in `your` Client request.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Find out the response (content type) returned by Service.
Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header.

So you will have to supply a different one which is acceptable to the server.